# Detect where non-speech loud sound exists in a speech audio file

Tags: audio

Is there a way to detect the positions (start and end) where other loud sounds than speech exist in an audio file? For example, the sound of tapping something, popping sound effect, mouse click sound effect, short computer-generated music, etc.

In summary, the conditions are:

1. The sound is not human voice.
2. The sound is louder than the average volume of the human speech in that audio file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of readily available open source Voice Activity Detectors. If the following conditions are met:

1. The given audio frame is NOT classified as speech and
2. The audio frame energy is above the adaptive threshold calculated on speech frames

classify the frame as "loud non-speech".

[RNNoise](https://github.com/xiph/rnnoise), a noise suppression library, has a very good VAD and the algorithm easily works in real time.

Here is a rough example on how to use the library to get the VAD:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rnnoise.h"

#define FRAME_SIZE 480

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i;
  int framepos = 0;
  float vad;
  float x[FRAME_SIZE];
  FILE *f1;
  DenoiseState *st;
  st = rnnoise_create(NULL);
  if (argc!=2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <noisy speech>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  f1 = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
  while (1) {
    short tmp[FRAME_SIZE];
    fread(tmp, sizeof(short), FRAME_SIZE, f1);
    if (feof(f1)) break;
    for (i=0;i<FRAME_SIZE;i++) x[i] = tmp[i];
    vad = rnnoise_process_frame(st, x, x);
    if (vad < 0.1) printf("Non-speech frame position %d VAD %f", framepos, vad);
    framepos += FRAME_SIZE;
  }
  rnnoise_destroy(st);
  fclose(f1);
  return 0;
}
```

I didn't compile it / run, so you might need to fix a line or two to get it working.

Comment: Thanks but the linked library does not seem to have good documentation or examples. Could you add a simple code example to determine the position (or frame) of "loud non-speech" in an audio file (like .wav, to be simple) using the RNNoise library?

Comment: @DamnVegetables Done. I leave to you determine what "loud" actually means. Compute the energy of the signal.